# Pre-Requisite for Graphs with Unique Topological Sort

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's assume that a graph in question is a DAG (directed acyclic graph).

**Question**: can I conclude that such graph will have a unique topological sort if, and only if, only one of its vertices has no incoming edges?

In other words, is having only one vertex with no incoming edges necessary (but not sufficient) to generate a unique topological sort?

Comment: Having one vertex with no incoming edges is a necessary condition for a graph to be a DAG. Otherwise it has at least one cycle and it would not be a DAG, so it would not have a topological sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haaaaa, ok. sorry for the misunderstanding.

In this case I assume that you are right, here is a sketch of proof:

We have a unique topological sort => We have only one vertex that it is legal to put in the first place => For every vertex, except one, it is not legal to put in the first place => For every vertex, except one, we have incoming edges.

Hope that now I answered your question....

Comment: I am not asking if my condition is sufficient (I know it's not), but rather if it's necessary.

Comment: @DanielScocco: "If and only if" means necessary **and sufficient**.

Answer (score 19):

A topological sort will be unique if and only if there is a directed edge between each pair of consecutive vertices in the topological order (i.e., the digraph has a [Hamiltonian path](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html)).  [Source](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/)

A Hamiltonian path just means that a path between two vertices will only visit each vertex once, it does not mean though that one vertex must have no incoming edges.  You can have a Hamiltonian path that is in fact a [cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html).  This would still generate a unique topological sort (of course it would be a cycle as well if that is important to you).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

No! The graph below has only one vertex with no incoming edges, and have 2 possible solutions.

```
1 -> 2
3 -> 4
3 -> 1
4 -> 2
```

Two solutions are:

```
3 1 4 2
3 4 1 2
```

Comment: Having a graph with only one vertex with no incoming edges is a necessary condition but it's not sufficient. The graph must have the Hamiltonian path as well.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has given the answer. Here I just want to give you a counter example: G = {(1,2), (1,3)}. In this case there are 2 valid topological sort: 1,2,3 and 1,3,2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can say that as a necessary condition as if there are multiple nodes with in-degree =0 then there will not be a Hamiltonian Path hence no unique topological order. Only for the starting node of graphs (in-degree=0) will have no incoming edge, rest all vertices MUST have an incoming edge from their topological ancestor, that means node just before the current node in topological ordering. If every consecutive node in topological ordering does not have an edge the DAG will NOT Have unique order.